# Displacement and rotation of the template pattern relative to the camera in 3D space

Tags: geometry, computer-vision

I have the template pattern (for example, rectangle), so I know it's size in mm. Also I have several frames with this pattern. So I know the intrinsic matrix $K$ of camera with which these frames were taken. And I want to find displacement and rotation of the template pattern relative to the camera in 3D space. 
The intrinsic matrix $K$ [has this form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHJ1Z.png)

where $\alpha_x$ and $\alpha_y$ represent the focal length of the camera in terms of pixel dimensions in the $x$ and $y$ direction respectively. $x_0$ is width of pixel dimensions, $y_0$ is height of pixel dimensions.
So how can I find displacement and rotation of the template pattern relative to the camera in 3D space?

Comment: The techniques described in chapter 9 of Harley & Zisserman seem like they’d be applicable to your problem.